# Relation between client side scripts and DBMS

Tags: javascript, mysql, actionscript-3, oracle

Today I heared something weird from someone, he said that using Javascript at the front end with Oracle DB that gives high performance than the performance if used Flash(ActionScript) with Oracle, while MySQL have the same performance with any client side scripting.
Is that right?, Does client side scripts have anything to do with DBMS ?

Comment: This is likely the wrong forum for such a question. Nevertheless, that does seem like a strange statement, since in most application configurations neither javascript nor actionscript are directly interfacing with Oracle, but rather with a webserver running something like PHP that does the interfacing with the DBMS.

Comment: A query is a query is a query it doesn't matter how it is run all that matters is how optimized the query is. And if you are writing your query from JavaScript/Flash then you have more issues to worry about then speed.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways in which a Flash application can connect to a database:

```
using the XMLConnector component;
using a combination of XML and CGI;
using the XMLSocket class.
```

It is important to realize that there is no direct way of connecting Flash to a database; an application is needed to act as an intermediary between Flash and the database.

Whereas regular JavaScript can't connect directly, there is no direct way to connect to Oracle. But serverside javascript or other server-side technology could be faster then the flash approach, may be that's what was meant.

I would think that the speed would be similar.